# How do I get reference to url-id in next page?

Tags: session, url, pdo

Using PDO, how do I search for the correct record "id" number transferred in the url string that was set up on my all_items.php page as follows: a href="details.php?= ?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> LinkHere$row['id']; ?>-- (modified so it shows up here, but it works on the page.)

It appears in the url going to the details.php, but how do I reference it on that page? Should I bring it in using a $_SESSION reference something like: 
$id=$row['id'];?> What would bring that $id variable into my details page without someone having to enter it?

I see a lot of references to using $_GET and the form method=get, but I'm not using a form on my details.php page. I'm using a SELECT statement and a table. Nothing should have to be entered.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What will happen if someone enters the value manually?

Comment: That's not an accepable method. I can already see the id number, I can click on it, and I can insert it into the url. Why can't I retrieve it on the next page and pull up the record from the same table I found it in? It's like the master/slave relationship in Dreamweaver It's a related record. I'm sure there's a way to do it.

Comment: No, When you see a list of records, then you want to click on any of them to see it's details, then you have to send the `id` of that record from the client to the server _somehow_. There is no way to send it secretly. You can encrypt the `id` or you can use `slug` instead, but there is still some data being sent from client to the server regarding that specific record and it **can** be manipulated by the user. It's your duty to validate it upon receiving it by the server-side code...

Comment: I understand the need to validate what's being sent if you're inserting or updating a record, but just to look at it--does that need to be validated too? I'm not trying to send it secretly. It's in the url! Everyone can see it! They can even change it if they want and pull up a different record. I'm just wondering how I get the "id" in the query that replaces the question mark in WHERE id = ?. It's just a fetch question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Then maybe I did not understand your question clearly. If you mean you do not have a `<form>` but you need to get the id, then all you have to do is to enclose the id in the link in your `all_items.php` file like this: `<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>` and then in your `details.php` file use this line of code: `$id = $_GET['id'];`. Tha's all. If this does not answer your question, then please can you please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: I have tried adding $id = $_GET['id']; in the details.php page BEFORE the SELECT statement, but using it in the statement as 'SELECT * FROM items where id = $id'; doesn't work! I get an error -- Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause' THIS IS MY PROBLEM. I don't know how to call it in the SELECT statement. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear. I know how to set up the link to retrieve the id number from the original search and to pass it to the url string. I just don't know how to ask for it in the SELECT statement so it can retrieve the ONE record I'm looking for.

Comment: I see you have entered an answer for this question, but you haven't answered it. You did provide some nice formatting for using a var in the SELECT query, but populating that var still hasn't been resolved. I'm no closer now than I ever was. I'll just have to wait for my new book to arrive and hopefully I'll get some clarification about how this all works then. Thanks.

Comment: I did my best to assist you on your problem, but to be honest I still do not know what is your issue. Your question is very vague. In your question you ask about `session` but then in your last comment you mention about a query _which you did not include in your question_ and an error _which again you did not include in your question_. So I suggest you first take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With this question, I think nobody can help you solve your problem.